# Can we have partitions within partition in a Hive table?

Tags: hiveql

Can we do partitions within partitions in Hive table.

I mean can we partition a partitioned table? or is bucketing the only option in Hive tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive supports multiple levels of partitioning. But keep in mind that having more than a single level of partitioning in Hive is almost never a good idea. HDFS is really optimized for manipulating large files, ~100MB and larger. Each partition of a Hive table is a HDFS directory. There are normally multiple files in each of these directories. You really should be closing on a petabyte of data to make multiple levels of partitioning in a Hive table.

What problem are you trying to solve? I'm sure we can find a sensible solution for it.